# How to show link preview in TableviewCell iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, preview

In my iOS app, its like converting audio/text to text and displays in `UITableviewCell`.

But, If the user pasted link in chat textfield like "some text https://www.somelink.com/,  I want to show preview of that page like how **facebook**, **Skype**, etc other social networking apps doing, I have less idea about this.

*I want to implement this in my `UITableviewCell`, Can anyone suggest me how can I move forward on this.*

I am doing this app in `Objective-C`.

Comment: This [library](https://github.com/marty-suzuki/URLEmbeddedView#use-in-objective-c) might help you.

Comment: @BhavinRamani if its separate outlet I can use, even I seen few, but I want to add in my tableview, how to do that? any idea?

Comment: You can use library suggested by @BhavinRamani .  You need to add URLEmbeddedView to the cell class and when you get url (if dynamic) then start loading url by method provided by that library.

Comment: You can use NSDataDetector to check for specific data, and modify your self to render it.

Comment: @BhavinRamani Ramani and vivek, I tried with above library, but its getting lot of errors with syntax in latest swift as I am not much aware of Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found solution for this. I have tried many ways to install the third party apis which is useful to show preview of website from a link, but, those are in swift, and my project is in Objective-C, but I was not able to install objective-c and swift pods into same project, got conflicts.

So, I just imported few XML/HTML parser classes and extracted the website title, image and description along with domain by passing the URL.

Following link helped me to extract website title, description, image and domain to show in preview.

**https://github.com/myell0w/MTDURLPreview**

I hope this will helps someone in future.